# A complex series with exponentials

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, complex-numbers, exponentiation

I have tried to solve this type of series :

$$\sum \frac{e^{i\, u(n)}}{v(n)} $$

For some $u,v$ an Abel Transform allow to find convergence, but for $u(n)=n^2$ and $v(n)=n$ I can't find an argument.

Also if $v(n)=n$, do you think there could be a condition on $u$ to have convergence?

Comment: If $v(n)=n$ and $u(n)=n\pi$ then you get the convergent alternating series for $\ln(2)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<sup>Not a complete answer</sup>

I'll take $v(n)=n$, since this seems to be of primary interest to you. One approach to proving convergence of the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n} e^{i u(n)}$ is to split it into dyadic blocks $2^k\le n<2^{k+1}$ and try to get a bound of the form
$$\left| \sum_{n=2^k}^{2^{k+1}-1} e^{i u(n)} \right| \lesssim  2^{(1-\epsilon) k} \tag1$$ for some $\epsilon>0$. Since $n\approx 2^k$ within this dyadic block, the series is then controlled by $\sum_k 2^{-\epsilon k}$, which converges. The hard part is to get this $\epsilon$ of improvement over the trivial bound $\le 2^{k}$.

The sum on the left of (1) is called an [exponential sum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_sum). When $u$ is a polynomial, [Weyl's inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weyl%27s_inequality) can be used. In particular, [these lecture notes](http://math.uga.edu/~lyall/Learning/WeylQuadratic.pdf) discuss the case of quadratic polynomial $u$. The effectiveness of Weyl's inequality for the sum $\sum e^{2\pi i\, p(n)}$ depends on the irrationality of the leading coefficient of polynomial $p$, which in your case is $1/(2\pi)$. I do not know if known results about the irrationality measure of $\pi$ will suffice for your purpose.

Comment: wow thank you very much i had somewhat forgot about this, i'm going to do the read, thanks again !